# How to convert xls encoded number in php

Tags: php, csv

I am working on a csv import functionality.But while creating csv using MS Excel,
MS Excel converts 806842000000 to 8.07E+11.

How can I convert 8.07E+11 to 806842000000 in php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to check that what you're describing is actually happening. Excell rounds numbers when it displays them inside cells that are too small to display to full precision, but you should check that it's not actually rounding them by clicking on the cell and viewing the actual value in the formula bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, actually. 8.07E+11 means 8.07 * 10^11 whitch is 807000000000. Excel has rounded the number and lost some precision.

You can however stop excel doing this - change the column type to text before saving to cvs. Text fields don't get rounded.

Comment: I got the point buddy,thanks for your valuable response.